# Jersey rest test fails because of session inside of resource method

Tags: java, rest, session, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I have Jersey rest api, but when I try to test it it fails because of I am getting session data there, so the questions is, how can I mock or ignore this session variable, which Jersey can't detect?

Here is a request from my test:

```
User response = target("/am/users/" + userId).request().get(new GenericType<User>() { });
```

Here is my resource:

```
@GET
@Path("{userId}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public User getUser(@PathParam("userId") String userId, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    User supportUser = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("USER"); // Here is where it fails.
    User user = userDao.getUser(userId, supportUser);
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Jersey test is not running inside a servlet environment, which is something that is required to work with the servlet APIs. If you are not aware, Jersey does not need to run inside a servlet container. If the case of using the [provider-grizzly2](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e17125), if you don't set up the test container, it will default to running the `GrizzlyTestContainerFactory`, which only starts Grizzly and an HTTP server, not a servlet container.

In order to configure the `JerseyTest` as a servlet container, we need to override two other methods, `configurDeployment` and `getTestContainerFactory`. With the latter, we need to return the `GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory`, which will set up the servlet container. In the `configureDeployment` method, we can configure the application, at the servlet level.

```
public class ServletTest extends JersyTest {

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        // configure Jersey
    }

    @Override
    public TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext
                .forServlet(new ServletContainer(configure()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

If you are using the `provider-inmemory`, it doesn't support servlet deployment, so you will need to switch over to the jetty provider or the grizzly provider.