# Registering and binding object created with a factory

Tags: java, powermockito, jersey-test-framework

how can I register an Object in JerseyTest which was created by a factory? 
All I get is the error: "There was no object available for injection at..."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
  public void setHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequestMock){
    register(
        new AbstractBinder() {
           @Override
           protected void configure() {
             bind(httpServletRequestMock).to(HttpServletRequest.class);
           }
        }
      );
  }
```

This works. But doing the same for an object created by a factory I got an error:

```
  public void setAnObjectCreatedByAFactory(Object myObjectCreatedByFactory){
    register(
        new AbstractBinder() {
           @Override
           protected void configure() {
             bind(myObjectCreatedByFactory).to(myObjectCreatedByFactory.class);
           }
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Use `bindFactory(YourFactory.class).to(CreatedType.class)`

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37345374/2587435), if you want the real request object, and not a mock

Comment: Hey thanks for the answers. But my service looks like this  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public List<IAccount> accounts(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context ObjectCreatedWithAFactory object) {....}. In my Service the object is always null...

Comment: So what's the problem. I gave you two different solutions. I would prefer the second. Please read the link

Comment: @peeskillet Yeah thanks. I have tried both both the first solution with mocks is better (no exceptions thrown). My problem is passing the instance of the object created by a factory to resourceConfig... It doesn't simply work... I could pass an HttpServletRequest instance easily... This factory constructor needs an HttpServletRequest as well... Maybe that a problem at mocking side (Powermockito / Mockito)...